# Using UCanAccess to read excel sheet instead of JDBC-ODBC Bridge

Tags: jdbc, ucanaccess

I tried to upgrade my server JVM to java 8 but I was surprised that Oracle has removed JDBC ODBC bridge from Java 8 !

I searched for alternatives and I found people here provide another solution by a library called UCanAccess but it's mainly for accessing Access DB not Excel sheet.

My question is, can I use UCanAccess to access excel sheeting using same JDBC ODBC bridge used on current application ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, UCanAccess is not what you need. Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org).

Comment: U haved used Apache POI before but i have a concern regarding the performance specially if you are dealing with large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCanAccess is for accessing a Micrsoft Access database through JDBC, so it cannot be used to access an Excelsheet. You could have found this information by looking at the [UCanAccess sourceforge page](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/):

> UCanAccess is a pure Java JDBC Driver implementation which allows java developers and jdbc client programs to read/write Microsoft Access database (.mdb and .accdb files). No ODBC needed.

As Stackoverflow is not for software recommendations, I suggest you use your favorite search engine to look for an Excel JDBC driver (they exist, but some of them cost money).